# Has the time gone to think about user with JavaScript disabled in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should I Bother To Develop for JavaScript Disabled?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-bother-to-develop-for-javascript-disabled)

In this Modern time of

- HTML5 API
- jQuery
- Modernizr
- HTML5 Shim
- Respond.JS
- Google Chrome app store
- Canvas

  Has the time gone to think about user with JavaScript disabled in browser? Ot it's still need to be consider

Comment: Modernizr does test whether js is enabled or not and if you want to present your user with a different view in that case, then you can build your CSS for the "no-js" view.

Comment: That is very dependent on what you are creating with JavaScript and what it will cost you for people to experience your website without JavaScript.

Comment: @YannisRizos - the question you mentioned is a year old

Comment: @JitendraVyas So? Most technologies you mention are quite older...

Comment: @JitendraVyas The accepted answer on that thread is as true today as it was when written.

Comment: @JitendraVyas do you honestly think anything has changed over the year? We support non javascript for other reasons then 'Those annoying customers who turn javascript off'. We support it because HTML and CSS should work without javascript.

Comment: Don't forget that there's a subset of no-javascript cases where "no css" applies as well.

Answer (score 14):

For web apps, yes, I think it's okay to require JavaScript because it's the nature of web apps to provide a rich, interactive user interface.

More simple websites like blogs, portfolios or brand websites should be able to work without JavaScript, in my opinion. I make all my websites work without JavaScript.

I know a few people who disabled JavaScript or block it with [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noscript/) due to security concerns or because they are annoyed of animations.

Comment: +1 For pointing out the difference between a website and a webapp.

Comment: Don't forgot about the blind, the crawlers, SEO and people using text based browsers.

Comment: @Raynos: Well, you really don't want crawlers to crawl through private data in web apps. So it is really a non-issue SEO wise. But if it is public facing data, then it should be viewable without using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It is as it has always been, IMO. It just depends if you want to target 100% of the population, or if you don't care about the M % who have a completely outdated browser, and the N % who disable JavaScript.

M and N tend to decrease, and I don't care about them much. But your boss or your investor could be of a different opinion.

I'd find it more important to make an app accessible to disabled persons (who don't have a choice), rather than caring about those who have a choice but choose not to use a modern browser with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: In my experience, M is decreasing, but N is increasing.  There's some fear of javascript out there that's causing people to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on your intended audience.

A personal blog on web development, for example, will have very few visitors with js disabled.

A business website, on the other hand, might have more old-fashioned business executive types who come to visit, and it may be very important to make sure the site is accessible to them. They are the customers, after all!

Comment: A blog on web development may have lots of visitors with Javascript disabled, at least on first visit.  Web developers are more likely than the general populace to understand the dangers of leaving JS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't considered this in a while for most sites I've worked on given the user base I typically have. Largely, it's a matter of knowing your user base and what they have enabled. You can use various analytics scripts to determine this.

Along the same lines, I am more careful now about providing a good experience on mobile devices when it comes to using Javascript widgets. For example, I avoid using a lot of resizing tricks since they cause problems with pinch-zoom and orientation flip functionality and dropdown menus since they're difficult to use on a mobile touch screen.